# How to select specific lines by group repetitively

Tags: r

I'm new here and a beginner on r, I already apologize if I'm not clear enough.
I need to read specific lines from a file containing this :

```
Année;1986;
;
Débits mensuels en m3/s;
;QMM;QMN;V;
J;;;;;
F;;;;;
M;;;;;
A;;;;;
M;;;;;
J;;;;;
J;;;;;
A;;;;;
S;;;;;
O;;;;;
N;;;;;
D;;;;;

Statistiques;
;;Janvier;Février;Mars;Avril;Mai;Juin;Juillet;Août;Septembre;Octobre;Novembre;Décembre;1986
Ecoulement mensuel;Validité;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;();;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;();;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;();;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;
Ecoulement naturel reconstitué;();;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;();;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;();;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;
Maximum instantané;();;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;Date;*;*;*;*;*;*;*;*;*;*;*;*;*;
;();;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;Date;*;*;*;*;*;*;*;*;*;*;*;*;*;
;

Débits journaliers;
Jour/Mois;Janvier;;Février;;Mars;;Avril;;Mai;;Juin;;Juillet;;Août;;Septembre;;Octobre;;Novembre;;Décembre;;
;Débit;Validité;Débit;Validité;Débit;Validité;Débit;Validité;Débit;Validité;Débit;Validité;Débit;Validité;Débit;Validité;Débit;Validité;Débit;Validité;Débit;Validité;Débit;Validité;
1;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
2;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
3;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
4;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
5;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
6;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
7;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
8;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
9;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
10;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
11;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
12;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
13;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
14;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
15;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
16;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
17;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
18;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
19;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
20;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
21;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
22;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
23;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
24;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
25;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
26;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
27;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
28;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
29;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
30;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
31;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;


Année;1987;
;
Débits mensuels en m3/s;
;QMM;QMN;V;
J;;;;;
F;;;;;
M;;;;;
A;;;;;
M;;;;;
J;;;;;
J;;;;;
A;;;;;
S;;;;;
O;;;;;
N;;;;;
D;;;;;

Statistiques;
;;Janvier;Février;Mars;Avril;Mai;Juin;Juillet;Août;Septembre;Octobre;Novembre;Décembre;1986
Ecoulement mensuel;Validité;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;();;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;();;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;();;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;
Ecoulement naturel reconstitué;();;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;();;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;();;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;
Maximum instantané;();;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;Date;*;*;*;*;*;*;*;*;*;*;*;*;*;
;();;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;Date;*;*;*;*;*;*;*;*;*;*;*;*;*;
;

Débits journaliers;
Jour/Mois;Janvier;;Février;;Mars;;Avril;;Mai;;Juin;;Juillet;;Août;;Septembre;;Octobre;;Novembre;;Décembre;;
;Débit;Validité;Débit;Validité;Débit;Validité;Débit;Validité;Débit;Validité;Débit;Validité;Débit;Validité;Débit;Validité;Débit;Validité;Débit;Validité;Débit;Validité;Débit;Validité;
1;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
2;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
3;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
4;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
5;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
6;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
7;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
8;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
9;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
10;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
11;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
12;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
13;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
14;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
15;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
16;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
17;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
18;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
19;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
20;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
21;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
22;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
23;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
24;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
25;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
26;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
27;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
28;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
29;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
30;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
31;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

I need to extract only lines between "Débits journaliers;" and the blank line after "31;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;", includes.
I've got more than 2000 lines on my file, because I've got all these data for more than 20 years.

My file is composed of character lines.

Thank's for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See whether the below helps

```
library(tidyverse)
file = read_lines("./Data/SampleText.txt")

grep("Débits journaliers;", file) %>% 
  map(~ file[.x: (.x+34)]) %>% 
  unlist # 2 lines after Debits + 31 lines + 1 blank
```